# What sizes can full item stacks be?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are there any items in Minecraft that stack to number different than 64, 16 and 1 (don't stack)?

Asking this as an avenue to tune hopper's time to go between "empty" and "full".

Comment: the max stack size is very arbitrary (it is possible to mod in a item that stacks to 50 but tradition lets it stay at 64)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, all items will stack to either 64, 16 or cannot stack.Most items can stack up to a maximum of 64 in one slot. Tools (with the exception of clocks and compasses) cannot be stacked. Certain items, such as Snowballs, Buckets, Eggs, Signs and Ender Pearls are special and can only stack up to 16.

This is for vanilla Minecraft (no mods) *only*! Items from mods can have any stack size.